# How can I create a Python script that runs in the background and can be stopped cleanly?

Tags: python, loops, daemon, shutdown

I have a python script that constantly runs (it has an infinite loop), but I want it to be able to still accept input while running. It will run in the background and then at any time I want to be able to type

```
scriptname stop
```

and stop it (or something like that). That way it can call a shutdown method to save information and quit.

Currently it runs in the foreground in the terminal, and can't be stopped by a keyboard interrupt, so the only way to kill it is to close the terminal or kill python.

How can I do something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `supervisord`. It exists to manage processes, and provides a command interface to start and stop them.

When supervisor kills a process, it sends SIGTERM (or any other signal you choose). So, to shutdown cleanly, you need to handle that signal.

See this question on how to handle SIGTERM: [Python - Trap all signals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148888/python-trap-all-signals)

Processes can still listen on their own pipes for input, and send output that way.

Comment: Is there any way I can use supervisord to send information into the script? Like in order to trigger the shutdown method? I want to make sure that it's not in the middle of doing something when it gets shut down.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Windows then You are at right point...

Just Rename your file: **`script.py`** to **`script.pyw`** and Use It Normally.
Your Script will run in background.

To close that script:
Go to **Task Manager** , click on **Process Tab**  , look out for **python** , **End Task**.

If You need more information I am Ready to Provide to you...
I am Not Sure About Linux or Ubuntu.
Thanks.