# write file even in case of any interruption

Tags: python, linux, file-io

How to make sure that file is written in case of any kind of interruption?
Consider this code

```
with open('output.txt', 'a') as FH:
    for i in range(5):
        mystr = 'some text %d\n' %i
        FH.write(mystr)
        time.sleep(2)
```

If this code is running and you interrupt it using Ctrl+c it still writes the output file.
But if you use Ctrl+z it do not write anything in the file!

Comment: What you want to do is catch the kill signal, and then ignore it.  Though you'll then essentially have an un-killable app, so make sure you don't have an infinite loop or anything

Comment: @wnnmaw You can still kill it with `kill -9`.

Comment: @Barmar, I think OP means to ignore *everything*

Comment: Do you mean you want to do all 5 writes, even if you interrupt it after 2 writes? Or do you just want to flush the buffer to the file when the user presses Ctl-C.

Comment: @wnnmaw You can't ignore signal 9.

Comment: @Barmar, shows how much I know

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148888/python-trap-all-signals

Comment: @Barmar I "just want to flush the buffer to the file when the user presses Ctl-C or ctl-z or any other kind of kill signal

Answer (score 3):

Flush the buffer immediately after writing it:

```
FH.write(mystr)
FH.flush()
```